# Heap Memory Overflow

Tags: matlab

I have written some piece of code for my program in Matlab 7.10.0 which has a graphical user interface, but sometimes i do receive this error on the command window:

> [ConditionalEventPump] Exception
>   occurred during event dispatching:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
>   space

And the system gets too slow...
Kindly help me with this,,how can i resolve this heap memory issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the amount of heap memory for the JVM, see [this "solution"](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18I2C/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences -> General -> Java Heap Memory and increase the heap size. Restart MATLAB and check if it works (if not, maybe you could consider increasing a bit more).