# Matlab memory management; insufficient java heap

Tags: java, matlab, memory-management

I was hoping that someone on here would be able to explain or point me to a webpage where I could learn more about Matlab's memory management. I know that Matlab is a higher level language so it takes care of memory management, which is good and bad. Good cause I don't need to worry about it and bad cause I have no idea what it is doing under the hood.
The reason I ask is lately I've been getting this error message a lot.

```
Insufficient Java heap memory to continue operation
```

Granted I'm using a mid 2010 15" Macbook pro, with only 4 GB of RAM, not really the best computer to be perform all the image operations that I do. I know Matlab has a delete function, and I didn't know when/if it would be helpful to use this function to save memory? I have used the delete function before only in hardware related tasks when I am sending data through serial I delete my serial object. But beyond that should I be using delete for my own memory management?

Answer (score 2):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790318/heap-memory-overflow). To prevent Java heap error, you will need to change JVM options. Change the default value in Matlab preferences or create a new [`java.opts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/java-opts-file.html) file with `-Xmx` (and optionally `-Xms`) options, e.g.,

```
-Xmx1g
```

Comment: That link to `java.opts` now says: `Do not use a java.opts file in the following situations: [...] To adjust the Java heap size on desktop versions of MATLAB [...]`. See my answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

To set the equivalent of the `-Xmx` parameter in more recent versions of Matlab, go to **Preferences** (on the toolbar/ribbon), then

```
MATLAB > General > Java Heap Memory
```

There is a slider there. Matlab will have to be restarted for this to take effect.

There is a [warning](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/java-heap-memory-preferences.html) about doing this, but as I [wrote elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42219107/1143274), I think it can be ignored.

---

In case you only have non-graphical access to Matlab through a terminal, the effect of the above command was to add the following line to `~/.matlab/R2016a/matlab.prf`, so you could do that manually instead.

```
JavaMemHeapMax=I36532
```

This line appeared after I used the slider to set the preference to 36,532 MB and quit Matlab. If you can't find your `matlab.prf` file, check [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/changing-system-preferences-programmatically).

Comment: Whichever method is used, to check that it worked, enter the following in the Matlab prompt: `java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`. This will give you a number in bytes, which should be similar to the `-Xmx` number you've specified.